# Pop-up js dialog box onclick table row and display php information

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-modal

I have a php site that displays table information from MySQL DB. I created a js that will pop-up upon clicking the row table. The problem is it will only function on the first row and nothing for the rest of it. And also I wanted to display the captured information from the row where it was clicked to the popup/dialog box. Thank you!

**Here's my Table**

```
<tr id="popup" style="cursor: pointer;">
<td hidden="text"><?php echo odbc_result($result,"OBGyneID"); ?></td>
<td><?php echo odbc_result($result,"Lname"); ?>
    , &nbsp;<?php echo odbc_result($result,"Fname"); ?>
    &nbsp;<?php echo odbc_result($result,"mi"); ?></td>
<td class="hidden-ob-xs"><?php echo odbc_result($result,"Bday");?></td>
<td class="hidden-ob-xs"><?php echo odbc_result($result,"pxAge"); ?></td>
<td class="hidden-ob-xs hidden-ob-sm"><?php echo odbc_result($result,"PhoneNum"); ?></td>    
<td><?php  echo odbc_result($result,"service"); ?></td>  
<td class="hidden-ob-xs hidden-ob-sm"><?php echo odbc_result($result,"obgyneTime"); ?></td>                                                  
</tr>
```

**Here's my JS**

```
        $('#popup').click(function(){
            swal({
                title:  'Are you sure you want to delete this record?',
                text: 'You will not be able to recover this record again!',
                type: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                buttonsStyling: false,
                confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
                cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-light',
                background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.96)'
            }).then(function(){
                swal({
                    title: 'Are you sure?',
                    text: 'You will not be able to recover this imaginary file!',
                    type: 'success',
                    buttonsStyling: false,
                    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-light',
                    background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.96)'
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: use CSS class instead #id to call click event to show popup

Comment: @ManojSingh im sorry, im not rely an expert of this. How? like like this? id="#popup". This doesn't work at all.

Comment: check added answer below

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to delete a record. So below code may be useful. You may have to pass your record id to be deleted in future
The #id variable must be unique for each row. Try below code

**HTML**

```
 <tr onclick="myFunction( <?php print $recid; ?> )"> <tr>
```

**JS**

```
  myFunction(recid){
      swal({
        title: "Are you sure you want to delete this record?",
        text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this record !",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true,
        closeOnClickOutside: false,
        closeOnEsc: false
    })
    .then((willDelete) => {
        if(willDelete) {

          // Here make a POST request to delete your record using recid paramter

        } else {
            // do nothing
        }
    });
 }
```

Feel free to ask doubts.
Please vote/mark this answer if it's helpful.

Comment: @MjEliad Bro don't use thanks or mentions in stackoverflow. Just upvote the answer or mark as helpful. That's best thing to support others :)

Comment: Hi, sorry this code did not work for me. dialog box is not showing.

Comment: You meant sweetalert.js?

Comment: i forgot to put <?php print $recid; ?>. Please check. This is working

Answer (score 0):

add class on TR tag

```
<tr class="popup" data-company="Google" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

change this class to call popup

```
 $('.popup').click(function(){

    var company = $(this).data('company');

     /* your code */

 });
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks alot man! May i know how to display information in the dialog box from the row where it was clicked?

Comment: you can add data values with TR tag and get that values in you JS method to show in popup.

Comment: Like how can i do that?

Comment: @MjEliad  i have updated my answer....to add data tag with TR and JS to get data tag values.

Comment: Hey, I used the code below, it did popup but will not display records.

**HTML**
<tr class="popup" data-recordid='<?php echo odbc_result($result,"OBGyneID"); ?>' style="cursor: pointer;">

**JS**
var recordid = $(this).data('recordid');

Comment: if you are able to get all records data using - var data = $(this).text();    and passing data variable in SWAL popup like - [ text: data, ]  Then, just update following line =  text :  data + recordid,

Answer (score 0):

Check below code. I hope it will help you.

```js
$('.test').on('click', function(){
 // this is your table id
 var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
  swal({
    title:  'Are you sure you want to delete this record?',
    text: 'You will not be able to recover this record again!',
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    buttonsStyling: false,
    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
    cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-light',
    background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.96)'
  }).then(function(){
   // Add your ajax code here
    swal({
      title: 'Success',
      text: 'Record Deleted Suucessfully',
      type: 'success',
      buttonsStyling: false,
      confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-light',
      background: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.96)'
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr class="test" data-id="1"> <!-- Pass your table id into data-id -->
    <td>Testing</td>
    <td>Testing</td>
    <td>Testing</td>
    <td>Testing</td>
    <td>Testing</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="test" data-id="2">
    <td>Testing1</td>
    <td>Testing1</td>
    <td>Testing1</td>
    <td>Testing1</td>
    <td>Testing1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="test" data-id="3">
    <td>Testing2</td>
    <td>Testing2</td>
    <td>Testing2</td>
    <td>Testing2</td>
    <td>Testing2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This code works to capture all datas in a row, but i want to capture just this ID in particular "<?php echo odbc_result($result,"OBGyneID"); ?>" refer to delete a data from my data base. Is there a way we can do that?

Comment: @MjEliad Yes it's possible check my updated code. if any issue let me know